# "Status" vs. "state"

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns

Can anyone explain what the difference between *status* and *state* is when I talk about the condition or situation of an object?

Here's what I got from Longman English Dictionary.

> *status*: a situation at a particular time, especially in an argument,
>   discussion etc.
>
> *state*: the physical or mental condition that someone or something is
>   in

For example, how do you interpret these two sentences:

> 1. What is the current status of this project?
> 2. What is the current state of this project?

Comment: I have read all the answers, and none of them were satisfying for me. This is a very good question but has very confusing answers! Maybe I'm not as advanced in English as I should have been in order to understand the answers. Anyway, up-vote!

Comment: Thisd is probably because there is no clear, general, distinction between the words. In some contexts only one is used; in other contexts they are interchangeable; and in still other contexts they can both be used and have different meanings. Welcome to English.

Comment: What is the current status of this project? -- its place in a hierarchy. ---- What is the current state of this project? Its condition.

Comment: From my understanding, State is "conditional" while Status is "hierarchical". Eg.: State can be ON/Off, while Status may be starting, processing, transferring, done

Answer (score 81, accepted):

A hotel room might have a status of standard, de-luxe or honeymoon-suite.
That same room may have a state of being dishevelled or clean.

A project progresses through a series of predefined stages. Its status tells you where it is in that series. Its state might be in disarray or on target regardless of status.

In considering this I asked myself two questions: What is the status of X? What sort of state is X in?

In reality, I suspect there is considerable overlap in the usage of *state* and *status*.

Comment: The status of that room is honeymoon suite? Not in my world.

Comment: I like hotel room analogy, except I would change the definition of status to be something like 'available', 'reserved', or 'under repair', rather than 'standard', 'deluxe' or 'honeymoon'. State would still describe the overall condition (clean / dirty).

Comment: standard, de-luxe or honeymoon-suite are types of room. However I like the questions: What is the status of X? What sort of state is X in?

Comment: I agree with the others; “status” is conflated with “type” here, but they’re not really interchangeable. There’s more overlap between status and state than between status and type. I think a better analogy is to look at it as a graph: “state” is a node, “status” is a directed edge, and progress is how far along an edge one is in transitioning between states. Where progress is 0% or 100% status may or may not equal state, subject to your mental model. In a hotel room, “state” can be “available”, “dirty”, etc., “status” can be “waiting” (0% or 100% progress), “cleaning” or “in-use” (1–99%), etc.

Answer (score 63):

In that context, *status* would refer to the progress of a project, e.g. in testing, in preliminary research, etc. *State* would refer more to the condition of a project, e.g. green-lighted, cancelled, on hold for financial analysis.

When referring to a specific object, you typically want to use *state*, e.g. cold, hot, liquid, solid (this refers to the object's physical state). The *status* of an object is rarely used or mentioned, unless it is something that moves or transforms, in which case it is used to mean distance or progress.

Comment: Thank you very much. I wish I can pick both as my answers...but the system won't allow me.

Comment: Funny, your first paragraph says exactly the opposite of how I would use these two words. For me, a state is more intrinsic (e.g, in a preliminary phase) while a status refers to the project in relation to something else (e.g., approved, cancelled, etc.).

Answer (score 29):

I find the systems engineering definition useful here. A system is in a certain "state" at a point in time when the system meets a pre-defined set of criterion, i.e. on shopping website, a user's shopping cart enters a different state when the customer adds an item to it.

A "status", in the context of states of a system, describes the transition into a state. For example, the user of our online shop may attempt to add an item to their cart. The transition into the state that describes the item being in the cart may be blocked if the status of the transition signals an error (i.e. the item is out of stock).

In systems engineering, these two words have very specific meanings. From the definitions above, it could also be inferred that a state exists (or does not exist) irrespective of time. A status, however, describes the outcome of an action at a particular point in time. The difference here, I think, holds true even outside the context of systems engineering.

In the context that you describe, the definitions above are still relevant. The state of the project maybe described as, "component A is complete but component B is not; the project is 60% complete overall". This description of the state of the project would be the same at any point in time given unchanged progress of components A and B and unchanged outside influences. The status of the project however would almost certainly change with time, likely with respect to a deadline.

Answer (score 22):

A simplifying proposal:

- *Status* is one-dimensional, i.e., it is determined by a single value (e.g., the social rank of a person, the amount of progress made by a project, the goodness of an outcome, etc.) usually ranging from good to bad, desirable to undesirable, or the like.
- *State* is “all the rest”: it is either n-dimensional (with n > 1), or it does not refer to something that can be ordered by quality. In practice, though, *state* is often used when the conditions for using *status* would apply.

In IT, executions at the OS level usually return an exit *status* (e.g., 0 for success), HTTP calls return an HTTP *status* code (e.g., 200 OK or 404 Not Found). On the other hand, we have (finite-)*state* automata that describe how a complex system (e.g., a parser) can go through its possible *states*. When we suspend a physical or virtual machine we cause its *state* to be saved.

Comment: +1 Nicely relates to @chharvey's "Status carries official or legal implications". In HTTP terms the outcome is coming from official standard, therefore status - single one dimensional result/protocol answer.

Comment: Makes sense to me, the best abstraction so far. What's the source of that quote?

Comment: Oh, sorry, it looked like a quote, but wasn't. I fixed that

Answer (score 13):

STOHDTO (Six To One, Half-a-Dozen To the Other). In a technical manual, there may be a clear distinction between these terms, however in the English language these words are synonymous. In fact, Dictionary.Com uses the term "state" in the very definition of [status (see #2)](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/status?s=t), and [vice versa (see #3)](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/state?s=t).

The difference is really open to interpretation. Mine is below.

In my opinion, a *status* is one of a pre-defined set of conditions, for example, **not ready**, **in progress**, **almost ready**, and **ready to use** (see http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/Property:State; ironically, WebPlatform.Org calls these "states", but I think they are more like "statuses"). I believe statuses should be arranged on a spectrum, and an object usually moves from one end of the spectrum to another, having *exactly one* status assigned.

*States*, on the other hand, are conditions that don't need to be arranged in any sort of order or on any spectrum. An object might possibly not have a state assigned. (Although I don't think it's possible to assign multiple states to an object. Usually people will refer to *"the"* state of [blank], not *a* state.)

More from Dictionary.com (emphasis mine):

> State, condition, situation, status are terms for existing circumstances or surroundings. **State is the general word**, often with no concrete implications or material relationships: "the present state of affairs." Condition carries an implication of a relationship to causes and circumstances: "The conditions made flying impossible." Situation suggests an arrangement of circumstances, related to one another and to the character of a person: "He was master of the situation." **Status carries official or legal implications**; it suggests a complete picture of interrelated circumstances as having to do with rank, position, standing, a stage reached in progress, etc.: "The status of negotiations."

Answer (score 7):

I find that most answers to a similar question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162816/naming-conventions-state-versus-status) (despite being technical oriented) are more clear and acceptable to me.

The short answer is that `status` defines (by selecting a value from a list of predefined names) one aspect or characteristic of some entity at some point of time, while `state` defines the entity as a whole including all `statuses`

Comment: It looks like indeed status means a defined/definite situation, e.g. servant status, or something on which everybody agree, e.g. social status, while state is a free descriptive assessment, e.g. state of health.

Answer (score 1):

Since we had a long discussion with a group oft software people, I add another example that reflects our results. The object of this example is a "package" that we used to understand the difference better :

- The package's **status** can be something like: ready, in delivery, delayed, delivered, lost
- The package's **state** can be: mint, broken, partly broken

So for our general understanding we defined it as:

- **Status** describes in what step of a certain process an object is. So an object can have one status per process (delivery status, payment status). You cannot perceive the status of the object with your eyes just by looking at the object isolated. (Looking at a package, you won't know if it has been payed).You need information about the process to know an objects status.

One could argue that you can perceive the status "delivered" by looking at a package that is located on your table. But if you only look at the package isolated (as part of a bunch of zoomed in photos) of a set of packages you can't tell which is delivered and which is still located at the sender because the information is not tied to the object, it must be perceived from outside, you need to know about the process.

- **State** describes the (physical) condition of that object. You can perceive a state with your senses.

If you consider the above argument with the bunch of photos, you will likely be able to tell if they're broken or not. At least if you had a pile of packages, and you can examine them more closely.

So for our understanding, something like a project that is not materialized in the real world can only have statuses but never have a state. In contrast, everything that you can name can have statuses.

Answer (score 1):

**state** is intrinsic, **status** extrinsic.

The *state* of something is its inherent condition, whereas its status is relative to an external framework of some kind.

A book in a library's rare book collection might be in a *fragile* **state** and its  **status** might be *non-circulating*.

A soldier's state might be *wounded* and his status might be *awaiting surgery*.

A lab specimen's state might be *frozen* and its status *to be discarded in 2029*.

Answer (score -1):

The project can be in the state of preparation, design, implementation or verification, while the status of the project should be more accurate, detailed depiction, such as 70% completed.
Roughly speaking a state is a series of sustainable and consistent status, a status is a slice of state at some special point.

Answer (score -2):

Status is the precision of describing the situation while state is a general description.

> Project state: It is in phase 4, we have some issues that are raised such as delays on deliverables
>
> Project status: Deliverable x is 2 weeks pass due , expert M still sick and can not come to work

Comment: \[[citation needed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Citation_needed)\]

Comment: “Deliverable x is 2 weeks pass due” is gibberish, not English. The “precision of describing the situation” also makes no sense, and the two examples (or the parts of them that make any sense) show no perceivable distinction in meaning. In all, this answer doesn't make any sense.